# How to create a bootable iso file from a multiboot USB

Tags: usb, iso

I want to make a bootable iso file out of my 6-OS `Multiboot USB`. How can i achieve the task.

Comment: I have to ask, why?  That way maybe there would be a different approach to it.

Comment: Ya i want make a virtual ide drive, i have tried many methods like trying to boot from usb in virtualbox but of no work. And also to create a virtual optical disk directly out of usb. etc.. no luck many errors .

Comment: Is your multiboot USB using grub2? If so remove reference to the iso's you don't want to boot from grub.cfg then delete the corresponding iso's.

Comment: I want to boot from all of them thats why i am searching ways so desperately.

Answer (score 0):

here is only described how to create one iso-file out of
several iso-files ...

http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100131184456AAs9iR8

in case of usb-stick you probably would have to create an img-file ... ???
have nothing found about that.

here is different link for windows-users:

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/combine-multiple-iso-images-burn-single-bootable-iso-image-file/